# Vscode eclipse formatter setting to align method parameters

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, eclipse-formatter

Which eclipse-formatter setting in vscode will accomplish the following formatting, focusing specifically on the parameter alignment?

**Current**

```
    public ResponseEntity retrieveAgreement(final String one, final Long someId,
            final Long anotherId, final Long otherPAram) {
        // Omitted
    }
```

**Desired**

```
    public ResponseEntity retrieveAgreement(final String one, 
                                            final Long someId,
                                            final Long anotherId, 
                                            final Long otherParam) {
        // Omitted
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Java Formatting, you can refer to [Formatting and Linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting).

Download [GoogleStyle.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) and edit the following settings:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="1" />
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

Then in vscode **settings.json**, set

```
"java.format.settings.url": "<local path to java-google-style.xml>",
```

You can keep the formatting style that you want instead of parameters being formatted to one line:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly the desired effect but this is a step in the right direction. We've got this interesting codestyle at work which isn't really standard practice it seems, and hence is not supported by tooling. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: @theBushman. You're welcome. If there's any solution update about this question, i'll let u know.

Answer (score 2):

This setting helped achieve the desired alignment format.

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation" value="18"/>

<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_parameters_in_method_declaration" value="18"/>

<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_parameters_in_constructor_declaration" value="18"/>

<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_record_components" value="18"/>
```

This is taken after changing up the settings in an Eclipse IDE.
[image]